# API Route change Server React

Tags: reactjs, fetch

so i've this situation, my API it's on localhost:5000 and on the React project i used proxy, so every fetch i do with

```
fetch('api/*') etc etc
```

he used proxy localhost:5000, but i've a problem when i used on one page with router different

it's try to proxy on

```
fetch('api/:searchId')
```

he used the router where i call the fetch, so on localhost:3000/movie/:searchId for example

he try to call fetch on movie/api/searchId how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a `/` at the beginning of the path given to `fetch`, it will use the given path relative to the current browser path.

Add a `/` in the beginning and the fetch will be independent from the browser path.

```
fetch('/api/:searchId')
```